# Error injecting custom service into another custom service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Now that I have my script files referenced in my view template, I am having trouble injecting the first one into the second one.

If I unplumb the dependency that LearnerService has on SCORMService, everything displays according to plan, but is of course nonfunctional because LearnerService relies on SCORMService to accomplish its purpose.  When I try to actually use my SCORMService within my LearnerService, I get Michael Bay explosions and sad trombones.

So, I'm using ngRoute. That might be important; maybe not.
I'll list my app.js, my script ordering in index.html, learnerServices.js,  SCORMServices.js, and controllers.js

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('client', [
   'ngRoute'
  ,'controllers'
  ,'services.proxy.scorm'
  ,'services.proxy.lms'
]);
```

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/SCORMService.js"></script>
  <script src="js/LearnerServices.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="view-container">
        <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**LearnerServices.js**

```
'use strict';
var learnerServices = angular.module('services.proxy.lms',['scorm-service']);

learnerServices.factory('LearnerService', [ 'scorm-service', function(){
    return true;
}]);
```

**SCORMService.js**

```
'use strict';
var services = angular.module('services.proxy.scorm', []);
services.factory('scorm-service',function(){
   var foo = {};
   foo.bar = "snazzy jazzy";
   return foo;
```

});

I seem to be attempting to corner the market on stupid mistakes today.  Can anyone see what stupid mistake I did this time?

Comment: Never mind my edit(removed) for the controllers and the partial. It's firing.  Was testing my change against wrong port (1 working copy and 1 ref copy.My partial was loaded into sublime from the ref one. )

Comment: did you just change your question after it was answered?  if so, it would be better to make a new one.

Comment: I edited it to ask another question that I thought was germane and then edited it again to remove it because it was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line should be:

```
var learnerServices = angular.module('services.proxy.lms',['services.proxy.scorm']);
```

Notice in your code you are saying the module has a dependency on `scorm-service` however the dependency for the module is on `services.proxy.scorm`

Comment: d'oh.  The module has a dependency on the module containing the dependent service and the service has a dependency on the service contained by the dependent module. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  Look at how your app is defined which is also a module.

Comment: yeah...my god, I'm rusty today. lol
I needed another set of eyes.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.

Comment: So maybe part of my trouble is that I'm trying to go through this too fast.  I'm adapting someone else's proof of concept written in vanilla js and jquery to using Angular.  The problems right now are just layered upon one another and my clock is ticking.

Comment: If you haven't already, spend 1-2 hours reading the Angular documentation.  It will be a good investment of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Load your dependencies first in your html. That'll help.